# XQuery: Getting average price of products grouped by category

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

My database (xml) is the following:

```
<db>
    <productLine>
        <product nr="4567">
            <name>Shampoo</name>
            <category>Care</category>
        </product>
        <product nr="4568">
            <name>Polish</name>
            <category>Care</category>
        </product>
        <product nr="7010">
            <name>Radio</name>
            <category>Electronic</category>
        </product>
        <product nr="7012">
            <name>Headphones</name>
            <category>Electronic</category>
        </product>
    </productLine>
    <stores>
        <store storeNr="1">
            <range>
                <prodInRange>
                    <nr>4567</nr>
                    <salesPrice>20</salesPrice>
                </prodInRange>
                <prodInRange>
                    <nr>4568</nr>
                    <salesPrice>40</salesPrice>
                </prodInRange>
                <prodInRange>
                    <nr>7010</nr>
                    <salesPrice>120</salesPrice>
                </prodInRange>
            </range>
        </store>
        <store storeNr="2">
            <range>
                <prodInRange>
                    <nr>4567</nr>
                    <salesPrice>25</salesPrice>
                </prodInRange>
                <prodInRange>
                    <nr>7010</nr>
                    <salesPrice>140</salesPrice>
                </prodInRange>
                <prodInRange>
                    <nr>7012</nr>
                    <salesPrice>50</salesPrice>
                </prodInRange>
            </range>
        </store>
    </stores>
</db>
```

I want to show the average price of products grouped by their **CATEGORY**:

Wanted Output:

```
<category value="Care">28.3333</category>
<category value="Electronic">103.3333</category>
```

Process: Avg of (20, 25, 40) and Avg of (120, 140, 50)

I already have the following:

```
let $db := doc("avgCategory.xml")/db

for $pro in $db/productLine/product
let $cat := $pro/category
group by $cat

return 
<category val="{$cat}"></category>
```

But I don't know how to output the avg price of the product categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already indicated in the new deleted answer, after the `group by` clause, the `$pro` holds your group so using `<category val="{$cat}">{avg($db/stores/store/range/prodInRange[nr = $pro/@nr]/salesPrice)}</category>` should compute the average salesPrice of all products in a group.